# Maclaurin series for $\arcsin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to determine the Maclaurin series for $\arcsin(x)$. I know that $\arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin x))} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I also know that we can derive the polynomial by making use of the binomial theorem and integration. 
My question is if there is another, maybe more straightforward, way (e.g. by only making use of the definition of $\arcsin(x)$ (and its derivative) and the Taylor polynomial) to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Why don't you just expand $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ as a Taylor series and integrate it to get your Maclaurin series?

Comment: @mryoumath - the derivatives aren't very nice to work with, I don't see why there would be a better way than the binomial theorem

Comment: @cato: The Taylor series of $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ should be pretty simple and integrating polynomials is not that difficult. What do you mean by the derivatives aren't very nice to work with?

Comment: My question is if there is another way. Let´s say you talk to someone who´s never learned about integration. How would you derive the polynomial?